# How to apply markup to every third item in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the following markup to display different image crop sizes, depending on the item number:

```
<?php 
    $images = get_field('portfolio-gallery');
    $size = 'full';
    if( $images ): 
?>
    <ul class="cf">
        <?php foreach( $images as $index => $image ): ?>
            <li>
                <?php if ( $index == 0 ) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['gallery-1']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                <?php } elseif ( $index == 1 ) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['gallery-2']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
            </li>
        <?php } endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However I want to know if it's possible to adjust this markup so that rather than specifying each number individually, I can tell it to apply the specific markup to every third item, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify that the markup should apply to every third item you could use something like:

```
<?php if ( $index % 3 == 0 ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['gallery-1']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
```

This would apply the given markup to the 1st, 4th, 7th etc. image, assuming that `$index` starts at 0. If you wanted to apply it to the 3rd, 6th, 9th, you would use `($index - 2) % 3 == 0` instead.

Comment: Nice one @Nick, one second difference

Comment: @RayA happens to me all the time! Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Nick, just what I needed :)